# How do I access Google Chrome's built-in adblocker?

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome

I have Google Chrome Version 64.0.3282.186 (Official Build) (64-bit) installed on Kubuntu 16.04.

I don't see any option to access the browser's adblocker which is supposed to be available since version 64:

```
chrome://settings/content?search=ads
```

highlights only `downloads` in `Privacy and security` > `Content Settings`.

But, according to https://www.howtogeek.com/342986/how-to-disable-chromes-new-ad-blocker-on-certain-sites-or-all-sites/:

> Scroll down a bit more, to the Privacy and Security section. Find the Content Settings option and click it.
>
> There are a lot of options here, but you’re looking for the one titled “Ads.” Give it a click.

I don't see one titled `Ads` unlike what is shown on the [How-to Geek page](https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/x2018-02-15_12h02_53.png.pagespeed.gp+jp+jw+pj+ws+js+rj+rp+rw+ri+cp+md.ic.5XzHSBjjV2.png).

I'm signed in to my Google account and the profile doesn't have any external adblocker installed.

Answer (score 1):

It is available in the latest build of chromium

https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium

The download is a binary in a zip file.

Download , unzip, and run the binary from the command line

Direct download:

https://download-chromium.appspot.com/

```
unzip chrome-linux.zip
cd chrome-linux/
./chrome
```

Screenshot 1 (content menu)

[image: Ad 1]

Screenshot 2 (ads menu)

[image: Ad 2]

Chromium is the same as chrome without the branding. Has all the same features including sync across platforms, sync with chrome, development tools, etc.

I suspect you have to wait for google to release a new linux version of chrome or the ubuntu developers to package chromium.

In the mean time you can use chromium from the link I gave you without damaging your system or chrome.

Comment: Thanks! I just found out that is available in my existing version of Google Chrome but I need to allow a lot of features that I prefer to keep off rather than on.

Comment: OK, well, IMO it is not a replacement for an adblock extension, it just blocks the most annoying stuff, and everyone is changing ....